# How can I quickly find the 20 most recently modified files on Mac OS X (instead of using Python)?

Tags: files, osx

Of course it's possible to take the output of `find . -type f | xargs ls -l` and pipe it to a Python script that would sort the lines and output the top 20.

But is there anything faster than that?

Comment: Pass `-mtime` or `-mmin` to `find` to reduce the number of entries the Python script has to parse and sort.

Comment: Someone down-voted the question. Why?

Comment: Probably because this question is not unique to professional server administration; an end user might ask the same thing.

Comment: I see, so this question should have been asked on stackoverflow.

Comment: No, definitely not.  StackOverflow is for questions about programming; not usage of the system.  SuperUser would be more appropriate.  (Writing the python script might involve a StackOverflow question, but your overall problem would not)

Comment: With brew (http://brew.sh) you can use good gnu tools.

Answer (score 4):

On Mac OS X (10.10.2), try this

```
find . -xdev -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -f "%m%t%Sm %N"
```

or run a `stat` directly

```
stat -f "%m%t%Sm %N" /path
```

From `man stat`

> ```
>  In order to determine the three files that have been modified most recently, you could use the following format:
>
>        > stat -f "%m%t%Sm %N" /tmp/* | sort -rn | head -3 | cut -f2-
>        Apr 25 11:47:00 2002 /tmp/blah
>        Apr 25 10:36:34 2002 /tmp/bar
>        Apr 24 16:47:35 2002 /tmp/foo
> ```

You could easily replace 3 with 20 (-:

Comment: This works: `time find . -xdev -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -f "%m%t%Sm %N" | sort -rn | head -n 20 | cut -f2-`, but it took 2 minutes, 11 seconds, so it's not quick.

Comment: You *are* searching the *entire* file system, so yes, it will take time. What is your definition of quick?

Comment: I'm looking for under 50msec.

Comment: This is how many files you can scan with different disk types in 50ms on paper, assuming 10ms, 50000ns, 20000ns and 10ns access times and ignoring overhead: HDD 5 files, SATA SSD 1000 files, PCIe SSD 2500 files, RAM disk 50 million files. Considering the numbers a RAM disk seems to be your only option if you absolutely need that speed. An alternative might be to cache the results.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -xdev -type f -printf "%T@ %Tc %p\n" | sort -n | tail -20
```

Comment: That might work on Linux, but on Mac OS X, it says `find: -printf: unknown primary or operator`.

Comment: Try to trim the amount of data being piped to poor overworked `sort`.

Comment: @ijt On OSX, with "brew" you can install usable gnu tools.

Comment: Which brew package has GNU find? `brew install find` turns up nothing.

Comment: `brew install findutils` should do the trick.